# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away - hosting company says to OPTIMIZE Magento :-(

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, performance

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
VPS server:
RAM: 6 GB RAM
Storage: 150 GB SSD
Bandwidth: 6TB
8 cores
```

Our Hosting company is Hostforweb.com They did this migration from a datacenter in Chicago to New York in December and we are now having serious performance problems (they said the datacenter in Chicago was too expensive). They even said they moved us to a fast machine on a fast node after we complained of performance problems. Today, the sites are loading extremely slow and we get the following Error when going to the Admin login page:

**There has been an error processing your request**
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

```
> Trace:
> #0 /home/oursite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
> #1 /home/oursite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
> #2 /home/oursite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
> #3 /home/oursite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
> #4 /home/oursite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
> #5 /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
> #6 /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',
> Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
> #7 /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(984):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
> #8 /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(107):
> Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->getDbConfig('web/url/use_sto...')
> #9 /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(703):
> Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->__construct()
> #10 /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(685):
> Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_getProcessor('Amasty_Fpc_Mode...')
> #11 /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340):
> Mage_Core_Model_Cache->processRequest()
> #12 /home/oursite/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #13 /home/oursite/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #14 {main}
> 
> Error log record number: 540972657870
```

Where can I find the Error log?

I made a ticket with the hosting company but they just answered this:

*Currently, I see 4.55 requests/sec being served by the host which is quite normal and cannot be considered as an attack. However, this causes over 100% load and this is the reason your website is slow. The scripts running in your Magento store require more server resources than your server is providing.*

**What can I do to make it work again? I restarted Apache, MySQL, and the entire server 3 times.**

PS: This is what they said about optimizing Magento:

### *I have checked your server and found that your website https://www.whateverplace.com/ is generating a large count of HTTP processes which is taking all resources of the server. This was already stated in the same discussion and you need to review your Magento store with a professional developer in order to optimize it.*

UDATE:

Now I'm able to go through the steps of placing an order but when I click the SUBMIT button - it gives the following Error:

```
> There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> No such file or directory
> 
> Trace:
> #0 /home/whateversite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
> #1 /home/whateversite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
> #2 /home/whateversite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
> #3 /home/whateversite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
> #4 /home/whateversite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
> #5 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
> #6 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',
> Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
> #7 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(984):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
> #8 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(107):
> Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->getDbConfig('web/url/use_sto...')
> #9 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(703):
> Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->__construct()
> #10 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(685):
> Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_getProcessor('Amasty_Fpc_Mode...')
> #11 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340):
> Mage_Core_Model_Cache->processRequest()
> #12 /home/whateversite/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #13 /home/whateversite/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #14 {main}
> 
> Error log record number: 539436288523
```

The orders have NOT been placed. And I'm getting it in the Admin panel as well.

Comment: Issue is something related to SQL queries. I think you need to check if there are any triggers set in your database and also check which query takes more resources.

Comment: @allysin What is your situation today?  Have not heard from you.  Thanks

Comment: @Wilson Hauck I completely missed your messages-sorry!The situation with our hosting company is so bad that I will setup new on a new host! The existing hosting company=Hostforweb lied to us! We were suppose to have 8 cores with 6GB RAM and did not have anything even close) Now they claim they put us on a 8-coes 6GB RAM VPS account but we still see many performance problems due to load spikes. When I raise a ticket-they say that another account on the same node is doing a backup and that's why OUR performance is affected because that apparently happens on a shared VPS account for $89.95/month?

Comment: @Wilson Hauck I never did the script optimizing - I am now just trying to solve a problem with our product photos not loading in the Product pages in Admin = https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249348/unable-to-see-the-actual-images-in-the-back-end  and waiting on Magento to release a stable verion of 2.3 and setup on that on the new host (hosting account)

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is with your Magento 1.9 Code and MySQL Queries that you have given....Check and verify whether all your Database Tables are added

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/173516)

Comment: @Mohit Kumar Arora....I had provided a General Answer....I will provide a Comment next Time....