# Unable to see the actual images in the back end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media-images, image-preview

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We had to have our hosting company do a full restore. Now most things work except for when going into the images tab in the Admin panel:

- it shows the BROWSE FILES and UPLOAD FILES buttons and those seem to work

**however, there are no photos visible in the Image column and it actually says: No image**

[image]

I can click on Browse files, select a file from a folder and upload it successfully - it confirms that by saying:

1.jpg (55.83 kB)  Complete

But still no visible images.

### **What can I try to do to fix this?**

---

**the last entry in: var/log/exception.log is this:**

```
2018-03-08T23:15:04+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Connection refused' in /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:277
Stack trace:
#0 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(167): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_connect('tcp://smtp.send...')
#1 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->connect()
#2 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#3 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#4 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Queue.php(98): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#5 [internal function]: Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#6 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#8 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#11 /home/thisISmySITE/public_html/cron.php(75): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#12 {main}
```

---

**This is what the console says during the process of uploading an image:**

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For
>   more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
>   File: 55c7f862cd1a4eefae384ccd2ce42493 HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
>   File: 06dc7ed0d3ba9cd48335ee3599697dbe DOM7011: The code on this page
>   disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337 File:
>   55c7f862cd1a4eefae384ccd2ce42493 SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property
>   'target' of undefined or null reference File:
>
> ### > 55c7f862cd1a4eefae384ccd2ce42493, Line: 538, Column: 36

**This is what was posted into the var/log/system.log file during me trying to upload an image in the Product page of the Magento Admin Panel:**

> 2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():
>   Entity: line 9: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config
>   line 2  in
>   /home/newthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 510 2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():   in
>   /home/newthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 510 2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): ^  in
>   /home/newthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 510 2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Premature end
>   of data in tag config line 2  in
>   /home/newthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 510 2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():   in
>   /home/newthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 510 2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): ^  in
>   /home/newthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>
> ### > line 510

This is how that section in

> lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php

looks like now:

```
public function loadFile($filePath)
        {
            if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
                //throw new Exception('Can not read xml file '.$filePath);
                return false;
            }

            $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
            $fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);
            return $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass);
        }
```

**I did change it to this and then got Errors (in /var/log/system.log) which I listed below...**

```
public function loadFile($filePath)
        {

    file_put_contents(MAGENTO_ROOT.'/var/log/system.log', $filePath."\n", FILE_APPEND);

            if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
                //throw new Exception('Can not read xml file '.$filePath);
                return false;
            }

            $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
            $fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);
            return $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass);
        }
```

---

**I changed the code exactly as it is above but I wonder if that is not correct? The messages I found in the system.log file are these:**

```
2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 2  in /home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2018-11-13T21:47:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

2018-11-14T13:37:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log/system.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 492
2018-11-14T13:37:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log/system.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 492

2018-11-14T13:37:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 2  in /home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 514
2018-11-14T13:37:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 514

2018-11-14T13:37:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log/system.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 492
```

Comment: 1. You're referring to images in the edit product section?
2. What happens when you save the product after uploading a new image, does that image show when you go back into the product?

Comment: yes Edit product section and I have done that and it does NOT show in the front end or back end.

Comment: Something is corrupted with your database or your permissions. What happens when you create a new product?

Comment: @Haim Thank you for trying to help. When I create a new product, I upload a new product photo, it gives me a message stating it was uploaded but does not show the photo in the back or front end. The product saves though and is visible on the front end...

Comment: when you go onto your server, is there a directory for `magento_root/media/catalog/product`?

Comment: @Haim Yes and it has other folders inside the product folder such as -,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9 etc.

Comment: And does that directory have the correct permissions?

Comment: @Haim What do the permissions suppose to be? I think in the course of troubleshooting before I set that folder and all folders and files underneath it to 777 and it still did not make a difference...

Comment: Which browser are you using?
Have you tried the same in Chrome?

Comment: What does you browser's console (`F12`) say after you hit "Upload Files"? Apart from that, anything mentioned at `var/log/system.log` or even `var/log/exception.log`? PHP error log is another file (usually located at /var/log/php*.log, but your webspace might have a dedicated log for this) that can help to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner I'm on IE - F12, go to Console (I have it on the bottom of the screen), select a file through BROWSE FILES... then click on Upload Files; the Magento Admin says: Complete but there is nothing in the Console down below...

Comment: Sounds good, probably a permission issue on the tmp folder used while uploading in that case - or something else; you'll need to check the log files mentioned above for a deeper insight.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner The system.log file is in var/log but it has 1.04 GB so it doesn't open. The exception.log is in var/log and only has 3.48 MB. I will post the last entry up in my original post. Shall I delete the system.log file?

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner which tmp folder are we talking about? I can try to chmod it to 777

Comment: remove (or rename) `system.log`, it will be recreated on the next page action anyways.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner I posted the console contents and what  var/log/exception.log has as the last post in there...

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner I renamed the system.log file and a new one was created as suggested. I posted the contents above in my original post...

Comment: these messages in your `system.log` state that there is some malformated .xml-file - whether or not this is the actual issue must be checked. You could try adding `file_put_contents(MAGENTO_ROOT.'/var/log/system.log', $filePath."\n", FILE_APPEND);` (since `Mage::log()` does not work here) as the first line inside the `loadFile()`-method in `lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php`. This should help you figure out _when/where_ the error occurs exactly (the line above the error message should tell you the path to the faulty xml-file) when Magento is processing an uploaded file.

Comment: If you are using porto theme then do merging JS from the admin and then try it.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner Would you please check the update in my original post? I am not sure if I'm inserting this code in the correct place and correctly? Do I need to change the Magento root part? My Magento root is just public_html on the server so it's web root I think.

Comment: @Ruhani - Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried this before (about a week ago) in an effort to fix this issue and it did not help. The whole site went down, my hosting company had to different things to bring it back and then recommended I would disable JS merging again which I did.

Comment: I had the same issue of images and JS merging worked for me, may be you can find the alternate way of site went down, just marge js, do content deploy, flush cache and then check images if possible.

Comment: @Allysin - yes, like this. `MAGENTO_ROOT` is a constant and will get you the right path automatically. Just try to upload a new image and then check the files mentioned in the system.log right before the error message.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner I put the code in exactly how I've listed it up in my original post and found the Errors also posted there. Did I do that correctly?

Comment: "failed to open stream" .. instead of `MAGENTO_ROOT` in that case try to specify the absolute path to the log file - as long as this error is show something is wrong.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner I'm not sure what the syntax for the absolute path needs to be? My var directory is on root (root is technically one directory above, but var is in the public_html root which is what I think this is talking about?) Shall I put the actual URL in there? (such as https://mysite.tld/var/log/system.log) Is it possible I entered the code in the wrong place? (please see above) Thank you.

Comment: @Allysin, what permission are set for the folders `var` and `media`, also check the owner and group?

Comment: @Black var = 755 and media = 777 I checked via the File Manager in the WHM. How could I check the owner and the group?

Comment: @Allysin, you have to connect to the server via ssh and execute `ls -lah`. Or you can connect via ftp e.g. by using filezilla and then look at the tab "user / group"

Comment: @Allysin, also notice the warning in your first screenshot. You have to upload the image in the right storeview.

Comment: @Black  I will check the owner and group later when I get on FTP. What do you mean by the right storeview? We have always just uploaded the images into products and then specify the websites and storeviews in the other tabs...

Comment: I thought that we can change the storeview but it doesnt work 8n thiscontext. The hint in your screenshot was misleading

Comment: @Allysin If you are still not running, POST the COMPLETE content of - 
/home/newnewthisISmySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php 
 - so we can see the details on ~ line 510.
 Please view my profile, Network profile for contact information and get in touch with me, when time permits. Thanks

Comment: @allysin  Better yet, enlist the services of www.magenX.com.

Comment: @Allysin Is your Magento running reasonable well today?  View my profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch via Skype, please.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Flash is enabled on your website/browser. Try your steps on a different browser to debug, and if that is your issue follow this quick Google guide here https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784

Comment: Thanks for that. I know what you mean. When I connect from a browser where flash is NOT enabled, the BROWSE and UPLOAD buttons do not appear. That is a different issue from the image not appearing though.

Comment: Permissions issue then perhaps? Or try to chown the folders to www-data if you're using a common LAMP setup.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the following file:-

> lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

Look for this line:-

> chmod($destinationFile, 0640);

Replace it with this line:-

> chmod($destinationFile, 0644);

Look for this line:-

> chmod($destinationFile, 0750);

Replace it with this line:-

> chmod($destinationFile, 0755);

Comment: I only found 1 instance of chmod($destinationFile,....  and mine says: chmod($destinationFile, 0666); I changed it 0644. I am unable to find the 2nd one at all (this one: chmod($destinationFile, 0750); ) Could this be the problem?

Comment: changing it to 0644 did not help. I will try to change it to 0755 now.

Comment: I've changed it to 0755, deleted Cache, re-indexed but it did not help.