# There has been an error processing your request after hosting fixed file permissions using an automated script

Tags: error, magento1.9.0.1

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We had to have the hosting company (Hostforweb) do a Full restore of our Magento site and since then, we were having a problem with the Images not showing in the Product Images tab on the back end:

[Unable to see the actual images in the back end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249348/unable-to-see-the-actual-images-in-the-back-end?noredirect=1#comment350902_249348)

I asked the hosting company to fix that.

They replied:

We have done the following:

> - Fixed the file permissions using an automated script
> - Fixed syntactic errors in index.php file which were confusing part of Magento functionality (most-probably inserted when you put the site
>     in 'maintenance')

Now, the front page loads. We can click on a product picture which loads the product page but there is an Error which comes up **AFTER** *clicking on* **Add to Cart**:

**There has been an error processing your request**
DirectoryIterator::__construct(/home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Packages/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory

```
Trace:
#0 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Modules_Affiliate_Factory.php(180): DirectoryIterator->__construct('/home/newmyrealstore...')
#1 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Modules_Affiliate_Factory.php(146): Shopgate_Framework_Model_Modules_Affiliate_Factory->getAllValidPackages()
#2 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config.php(1155): Shopgate_Framework_Model_Modules_Affiliate_Factory->getModuleTrackingParameters()
#3 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config.php(1136): Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config->addAffiliateParameterToRedirectable()
#4 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config.php(273): Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config->getRedirectableGetParams()
#5 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config.php(211): Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config->toArray()
#6 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Helper_Config.php(175): Shopgate_Framework_Model_Config->loadConfig(NULL)
#7 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Mobile_Redirect.php(53): Shopgate_Framework_Helper_Config->getConfig()
#8 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(888): Shopgate_Framework_Model_Mobile_Redirect->_construct()
#9 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24184): Varien_Object->__construct(Array)
#10 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('Shopgate_Framew...', Array)
#11 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21764): Mage::getModel('Shopgate_Framew...')
#12 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14207): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14838): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(126): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14087): Mage_Checkout_CartController->preDispatch()
#17 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18482): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#18 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18016): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20808): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

### Error log record number: 595222511337

### **Where can I find the log record number? I looked in var and cannot find it anywhere. I used to have a folder with all the Error numbers. Is it possible that we turned that off somewhere?**

There are so many Errors in var/report.

This is the newest one:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:357:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'newflowe_myrealstore.mg_core_url_rewrite' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mg_core_url_rewrite` AS `rewrite` WHERE (request_path IN ('index.php/super-longstem-white-rose-arrangment-36965.html', 'index.php/super-longstem-white-rose-arrangment-36965.html/')) AND (id_path LIKE 'category/%')";i:1;s:1764:"#0 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(64992): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54273): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55316): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(56176): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54621): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front.php(1355): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front.php(361): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->isCategoryPage()
#8 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front.php(411): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->getNormalizedUrl()
#9 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front.php(778): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->getCacheKey()
#10 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front.php(1407): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->fetch()
#11 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(687): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->extractContent(false)
#12 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20794): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->processRequest()
#13 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/newmyrealstore/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}";s:3:"url";s:58:"/index.php/super-longstem-white-rose-arrangment-36965.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

---

**The hosting company fixed this:**

*I have checked the error and found that this script is constructing path to Magento packages with wrong directory:
/home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Modules_Affiliate_Factory.php
Then manually removed the "Packages" pointer in the location iterator function
getAllValidPackages()
This fixed the issue for now, but it seems the installation is not working properly and probably upcoming code integration issues will occur.*

**I'm not really sure what that means?**

Comment: You can find the same under var/report. You can enable this my renaming local.xml.sample with local.xml errors folder.

Comment: @Ramkish I found it thanks. I posted my newest Error up in my original post if it helps any?

Answer (score 0):

**The hosting company fixed this:**

*I have checked the error and found that this script is constructing path to Magento packages with wrong directory:
/home/newmyrealstore/public_html/includes/src/Shopgate_Framework_Model_Modules_Affiliate_Factory.php
Then manually removed the "Packages" pointer in the location iterator function
getAllValidPackages()
This fixed the issue for now, but it seems the installation is not working properly and probably upcoming code integration issues will occur.*

**I'm not really sure what that means?**