# Unable to add images in Magento 1.9. Is it possible to create a new product, upload the photo to a folder & reference photo directly in the database?

Tags: product-images

**Magento 1.9.1 Porto theme**

We had a major problem, had to do a full restore but ever since we are not able to work with product images on the backend.

This is not the issue with flash/browser. It is a long story that is detailed here:

[Unable to see the actual images in the back end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249348/unable-to-see-the-actual-images-in-the-back-end?noredirect=1#comment365247_249348)

*What I'm after now is a work-around.* **We need to add new products to the site urgently. Can I create a product, upload the product photo directly into a folder on the server via FTP and then go to the database, find the correct row and add the reference to the photo's location directly in there?** *How would one do that?*

---

**Updated February 11th:**

I've decided to do what was suggested by HelgeB and that is:

1. I did an All Products export using Dataflow
2. I then deleted all but the new products
3. I found the column labeled: image - since there was the following in there:

[image]

I created an import directory under media and then /i/m/ folders and I've put the product photos in there named exactly the same: such as /i/m/images2_2_1.jpg

4. I ran the import, deleted All Cache and re-indexed but the product photos did not appear.

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

I went into the database and found the product and it actually has the correct file name and path to the image:

[image]

That is the correct ID and all - yet the product does NOT show on the product on the front end.

Comment: you want to directly programatically product create?

Comment: @Rakesh Donga I was hoping to create the product in the Admin panel (it let's us do that), then upload the product photo into some folder on the server, then go to the database, find the product somewhere in a row and put the reference to the product photo in there so that it would then show the product with that product photo on the front end. Is this possible and if so - where would I look in the database and how exactly would I do that?

Comment: you can try this way working fine for me i have used this link
https://popatkaran.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/create-simple-product-programmatically-magento/

Comment: Why don't you use an import tool like Dataflow for adding the new products? I know, you used that already for migration :-) I guess it's easier and safer to create a csv file, upload image files to the server and run the import.

Comment: @HelgeB - that's brilliant! I can't believe I didn't think of that! Would this work you think: 1. create the products in Admin 2. Export only those new products through the Dataflow 3. open up the Excel file and add references to the product images 4. Put the product images in those folders in the import folder 5. Run the import via Dataflow ? I'm super-excited about this now :)

Comment: Can you please look at my update above?

Comment: Strange. Do you find the images in media/catalog/product/i/m/ directory? Is something in logfiles? Does the media directory and the subdirectories have the correct permissions (i.e. webserver user needs the right to write files)?

Comment: @HelgeB This is a true nightmare! The import seems to work because it updates the product's status (I created the products manually and set them all but 1 to Disabled; after the import runs - they are ALL set to Disable). The product images are in those respective folders in public_html/media/catalog/product/i/m/ but that's because I put them there - was I not suppose to do that? I will try deleting them and run it again...the permissions as far as I can see are all set correctly. How does one check permissions for the webserver user? Where to check the logfiles?

Comment: I guess that's a permissions issue on your server. If you can't upload files from the admin panel it can also be because of permissions. Please change the permissions for the whole media directory to 777, for example on linux systems run `chmod -R 777 media` in the document root. If you are using a FTP client check its help.

Comment: @HelgeB the entire media directory (and all subfolders) have been set to 777 for ages (I double-checked every directory 10 minutes ago)

Comment: @HelgeB I might just give up on the old server and try to think up a way to re-import on the new server which would INCLUDE the custom options (apparently, the Dataflow import does not have those fields). The big question is - can I keep the products in and then run the regular import on top of the Dataflow import already run just to update the custom-options? What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: We are really stuck - old server is horrible (performance - it's more down than up and we are unable to add new products to it) while the new Magento on the new server is almost ready but missing those custom-options! :-(

Comment: An update of products with the custom options should be possible. I have never done that before but in theory it should work. Give it a try with 1-2 products. Good luck :-)

Comment: How long should it take? I deleted these columns from the file: category, root category, stores (because they were throwing up Errors) and clicked the IMPORT button. It now says: Please wait and the circle has been going around for almost 20 minutes...

Comment: @Rakesh Donga Is it possible to import only custom options using your script?

Comment: yes possible but coding is different